# OpenAPI difference between CSharp and CSharp-NetCore generator

Tags: c#, .net, openapi, openapi-generator

OpenAPI generator offers two C# generators [`csharp`](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/csharp) and [`csharp-netcore`](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/csharp-netcore/).
What might be the difference between them? I could not spot it by looking at the generated code.

Comment: Make sense to ask their support, these kind of questions are off-topic here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csharp` only supports old .net framework such as 3.5, 4.0, 4.5 while `csharp-netcore` supports the newer framework:

```
        netstandard1.3 - .NET Standard 1.3 compatible
        netstandard1.4 - .NET Standard 1.4 compatible
        netstandard1.5 - .NET Standard 1.5 compatible
        netstandard1.6 - .NET Standard 1.6 compatible
        netstandard2.0 - .NET Standard 2.0 compatible
        netstandard2.1 - .NET Standard 2.1 compatible
        netcoreapp2.0 - .NET Core 2.0 compatible
        netcoreapp2.1 - .NET Core 2.1 compatible
        netcoreapp3.0 - .NET Core 3.0 compatible
        netcoreapp3.1 - .NET Core 3.1 compatible
```

You can run `openapi-generator config-help -g csharp` or `openapi-generator config-help -g csharp-netcore` to find out more about these generators.

UPDATE: csharp-netcore was renamed to csharp in v7.0.0 release.

Comment: i guess the better choice for me should be `netcore` because i'm going to use it with unity and unity does not support .net framework, thanks

Comment: for unity, you may also consider the csharp-dotnet2 client geneator